# Proof that n-dependent Set in Graph theory is NP Complete

Tags: graphs, np-complete

Consider an undirected graph $G$. A subset $S \subseteq V(G)$ is n-dependent if for every $x \in S, d_{<S>}(x) \leq n-1$. The n-dependence number of $G$, denoted $\beta_n(G)$, is maximum cardinality of an n-dependent set of $G$. That is, the n-dependence number of $G$ is the maximum cardinality of a subset of vertices $S$ such that $\Delta(<S>) < n$.

Consider the following question:

**Instance**: Given a graph $G$ and positive integers $n$ and $k$

**Question**: Does there exist $S \subseteq V(G)$ such that $S$ is an n-dependent set and $|S| \geq k$?
Prove that the n-dependent set problem in undirected graphs is NP-complete

This was a midterm question and my answer was this:

> For the sake of argument let's assume that there exists an algorithm $\mathcal{A}(G, n, k)$ that can solve the given problem in polynomial-time. Now let's say we are given an undirected graph $G$ with a number $k$ and are asked to check if the graph contains an independent set of size $k$. To solve this problem in polynomial-time, we are going to call $\mathcal{A}(G, 1, k)$. But since the independent set decision is NP-complete, we can't solve it in polynomial-time, hence $\mathcal{A}$ does not exist.

I can't understand why this answer is wrong (I got 0). Please explain.

Comment: You grasped the main idea (that this is a generalisation of IS), so if partial marks can be awarded I think you should get some. However, we don't *know* that NP-complete problems cannot be solved in poly-time (that's just conjecture at this point), so your last sentence does not follow. Instead, don't assume that $\mathcal A(G,n,k)$ is poly-time, and conclude: "Since the IS decision problem is NP-complete, every problem in NP can be transformed into it in polynomial time, ...

Comment: ... and since this is equivalent to $n$-dependence with $n=1$, every problem in NP can be transformed into $n$-dependence in polynomial time, so $n$-dependence is NP-hard." (Very longwinded but explicit.) To go from NP-hardness to NP-completeness, you need to show that the problem is in P (which is trivial here, as usual). I think you should also be more explicit that setting $n=1$ for this problem makes it *equivalent to* IS -- saying "we are going to call" does not quite communicate this logical relationship.